# Process.Start() does nothing

Tags: c#, cmd, vpn

I have to start a VPN connection (Fortinet) by code.
I have a cmd file that establish the connection.
If I call the cmd file on the shell it works pretty fine.
When I call it via Process.Start it does nothing.
It doesn't throw any exception, it seems to execute but VPN does not connect.

On the standard output I can read the echo I put on the cmd file (so it is executing the right file).
I launched a ping -d to see when the vpn goes up, when I call it via shell it goes up in a few seconds, via C# it is not.

I also tried a sleep(30000) but nothing.

My cmd (ConnectFile.cmd):

```
@echo off
@echo Connecting to VPN
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fortinet\SslvpnClient\FortiSSLVPNclient.exe" connect -s "vpn myvpn"
```

My code (connectFile and disconnectFile are strings that contain the full path of the cmd files):

```
try
{
    var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = connectFile;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(connectFile) ?? "";
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
    base.GetFiles(folder);
}
finally
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(disconnectFile);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the "current directory" is important?

Comment: why `UseShellExecute = false;`

Comment: How long would you expect `FortiSSLVPNclient` to take? (Ie. is it long enough so you would see the `cmd.exe` instance starting up). If not long consider putting a delay in the batch so you can ensure the batch file is running. Summary: find the simplest part of this you can work on: does the batch file execute at all?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When I manually call the cmd file the vpn connects in about 6 seconds.

Comment: Orthogonal to your question, but perhaps you should wait for the process to exit before continuing, eg. `process.WaitForExit();`.

Comment: I cannot do that, since the command will exit only when disconnected from the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the parameters. `FileName` is for the exe file, not the whole shell command (you're explicitly saying *not* to use the shell). So put the parameters to the `Arguments` property in `ProcessStartInfo`.

In your case, the parameters should be:

- FileName - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Fortinet\SslvpnClient\FortiSSLVPNclient.exe` (no quotes)
- Arguments - `connect -s "vpn myvpn"` (again, no quoting)

Second, you have to read the standard output if you capture it. If the output buffer gets full before you read it, the called process will stop working - it has to wait for the buffer to be emptied. If you're *sure* the application will actually finish at some point, simply remove the `Thread.Sleep` and call `ReadToEnd` right away. Otherwise, use eg. asynchronous reading to get the data.

Also, it's usually a good idea to set `WorkingDirectory`. Even if the application doesn't *need* any data from the working directory, it's safer, since only admins can change `Program Files` - this helps against DLL inject hacks.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I do not have any parameters. The "connect -s" arguments are inside the cmd file. I'm reading the StandardOut in the Tacer.Log call, but I redirected stdout trying to debug the code. At the beginning I was simply calling Process.Start with no redirection

Comment: @WaveMax Oh, you're trying to start the `cmd` file? Why would you think that could work? Unless you use `UseShellExecute`, you can only start actual executables (`exe`, `com`, ...) - `cmd` files are shell scripts. So either call the executable directly (as I've written in my answer), or start the program `cmd` with the argument being the cmd file. And do note that output redirection changes the behaviour of the application, so it might be a better idea to add eg. ` > some.log` to the application call inside the `cmd` file, which will redirect to a file instead, and use `UseShellExecute`.

Comment: I use a cmd file because I don't want to know inside the application how the vpn is established. So I delegate to a cmd file with all the arguments needed (I have other vpns that work fine using this method). I edited the question showing how it originally was, without the redirection. By the way, I just tried to invoke the .exe using arguments in the StartInfo, but again it's not working.

Comment: @WaveMax Well, that's weird. What does the error output say? And does the VPN software have some logs of its own? How is this particular VPN script different from those that work? Does your C# application have enough permissions to actually run the exe?

Comment: My C# application runs with administrator rights. Other scripts use different VPN clients (Cisco, Windows VPN). VPN Client's log says nothing, StrErr is empty.

Comment: Ok, I think I isolated the problem. I was running my app from Scheduled Tasks using the "Run whether the user is logged or not" flagged. If I run it with double-click, or if I flag the "Run only when user is logged on" it works fine. But I need to run the the application daily even if no users are logged on...

Comment: @WaveMax ... does your C# application have an UI? Applications with UI will *never* (well, there's a hack, but don't) work when you check "run whether the user is logged in or not". You might want to create a windows service instead. Also, console redirects to a file are extremely handy in such a case. Also, running as the admin isn't enough - make sure you check "Run with highest privileges" as well.

Comment: My application is a commandline, so no UI. The problem lies in the VPN client program that has a UI (from commandline you can hide the UI, but it still has it). My problem is that as far as it concern my application I can change it, but now I have to look for a pure commandline client for that VPN.

Comment: @WaveMax Yeah, that's the problem. From Windows 7 on, Session 0 is forbidden from using UI completely. Are you sure you can't have a user logged in all the time for the task to run? If you enable user switching, you can have a special user in the background, only for your application. Of course, an UI-less client is still the optimal solution, but this might be a useful "hack" which isn't too nasty.